# How can I get the user jabber Id in a chat room using AnyEvent::XMPP?

Tags: perl, xmpp, anyevent

There is a way to get the user's nick(roomName@domain.com/nick) in the chatroom according to the document, but  how can I get the user's real jid(name@domain.com/resource_name)?  is it possible according to XMPP protocol?

Answer (score 2):

You can unless the room is anonymous. The Jabber protocol makes it possible that people in a chat room may be anonymous so that you cannot get back to their real JID. This is also why it provides a private message chat within the rooms, so you can still private message someone who has done this.

I have some code that does this in [Bot::Backbone::Service::JabberChat](http://metacpan.org/module/Bot%3a%3aBackbone%3a%3aService%3a%3aJabberChat):

```
# Figure out who sent this message
my $from_user = $room->get_user($xmpp_message->from_nick);

# Prefer the real JID as the username
my $from_username = $from_user->real_jid // $from_user->in_room_jid;
my $from_nickname = $from_user->nick;
```

See [AnyEvent::XMPP::Ext::MUC::User](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aXMPP%3a%3aExt%3a%3aMUC%3a%3aUser) and [AnyEvent::XMPP::Ext::MUC::Room](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aXMPP%3a%3aExt%3a%3aMUC%3a%3aRoom) for more details.

Comment: Actually I read your module code before I asked here :)  Anyway, I find I have to grant my bot account admin privilege to see the real JID and now I can get it by using this code.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, OpenFire (and it's 6+ year old predecessors) must allow `real_jid` to work for all accounts by default. That's all I've actually tested the code on.